# How to stop a HTML5 video not using pause()?

Tags: html, html5-video

Is there a way to stop a HTML5 video without using `pause()`?

I don't want to stop the video with `pause()` because then I trigger my pause event handler. Also setting `currentTime` to video end is not a solution, because that will also trigger custom event handling for the `ended` event.

Comment: Can you send another parameter to the pause event? Alternatively set a global triggerPause = true/false variable and check that in your handler.

Comment: yes, that would be an okay work around

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Added my comment in the question as an answer] An easy but no the best solution would be to create a variable and check in the custom handler.

```
var triggerPause = true;

function customPauseHandler(e)
{
    if (!triggerPause)
        return;

    ...
}
```